# Storing Objects on the Stack

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Is it possible to alloc space for objects on the stack? I don't want to contest
the language principles, and yes, auto-release pools work very nicely. It's
just a matter of curiosity (and of investigating it). I've heard of things
like:

```
struct {
    Class isa;
} s_obj;

s_obj.isa = [NSObject class];

NSObject *obj = (NSObject *)&s_obj;
```

But I'm not sure if this will work properly. At least, it doesn't sound very
practical since the structure of the object would need to be re-created.

Maybe overwriting `+alloc`, and somehow calling an `alloca()` behind the
scenes? Looks like passing a different zone in `allocWithZone:` would be the
best approach, but NSZone is quite undocumented. CocoaDev [has an article](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZone)
on it, but again I'm not sure if it's the way to go. Any ideas?

Eventually, if an easy to use solution appears it would be nice to use it in
addition to the already present language features.

Comment: This is an interesting thought experiment, at least. If I had time to waste I might try it and see how far I could get.  It's doubtful that you could achieve anything that is both sufficiently robust and sufficiently useful to actually use the technique in "real" code, though.  (But then people said my scheme for writing native methods in Java was crazy, but it worked quite well, for some impressive performance gains.)

Comment: Agreed;  anyone who is interested in diving deep in Objective-C and the runtime really should consider writing their own root class that supports whatever wild ideas they might have.  The Objective-C runtime, itself, is remarkably flexible.   NSObject & friend introduce limitations as a part of the conventions of the frameworks.  Start with a clean root class and you can do all kinds of whacky-cool stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope;  can't do that.  Or, technically, you *can*, but you cannot pass the object to *any* system API and you *can't* subclass NSObject.

The system assumes that the object is in the heap;  autorelease will work as expected, and the object's lifespan can be controlled by managing a retained reference, none of which will be true for a stack allocated object.

(There is one exception;  Blocks start out on the stack sometimes.  Very special case and it is entirely controlled by the compiler.  It also trips people up.)

---

`alloca()` won't work;  the memory will be "allocated" (the stack pointer will be bumped) in the frame that did the allocation.  As soon as you try to return the object, the allocation is gunk and the returned reference is now a dangling pointer.

`NSZone` is deprecated in all but declaration.  OpenStep tried to perpetuate zone based allocations for the purpose of quick destruction back in 1994 or so.  Proved to be way too fragile;  there were way too many ways that a reference to a zone could escape into another zone and zone destruction would produce dangling pointers.

---

*Capturing what was in comments on Daniel's question*

- Once the stack frame containing a stack allocated object is destroyed, any references to that object are invalid.  Thus, any messages to any references will have undefined behavior and will, quite likely and at best, crash outright.  I.e. you can't set the retain count to some super high value because the call to `release` is already too late in that it will dereference through the now-invalid object reference to try and obtain the `isa` to try and execute the method.
- You cannot subclass `NSObject` in such an object because `NSObject` carries with it a boatload of functionality, both public like KVO, KVC, and associated objects, and various private implementation details of the system frameworks.   Any of this functionality should be free to retain/release/autorelease the instance at any time because a *fundamentally a `retain` guarantees an object's lifespan until `release` when subclassing NSObject*.
- You can't test for "working" behavior because any assumptions related to retain/release/autorelease of the system provided frameworks are inherently implementation details that may change across any software update for any reason.

Comment: Not suggesting anyone actually does, but what if you override dealloc and don't call super?

Comment: @Chris Devereux: You're still violating invariants of NSObject such as "This object will be around until it has enough releases to balance its retains".

Comment: Too late;  you'll crash when trying to message the dangling pointer as the `isa` slot is already likely blasted.  While Chuck's statement is correct, it is orthogonal;  think of it more as the sequence `NSPoint *p = malloc(sizeof(NSPoint)); free(p); p->x = 5.0;`

Comment: Yes, I know it would be a dangling pointer after the frame is gone, but creating objects on stack would serve the purpose of using them, well, on the stack (frame). I'd never use such object outside it. By the way, this is exactly the purpose: not to worry about freeing that memory.

Comment: I was thinking more about avoiding `NSPoint p; free(&p);`. But sure, that's not much good if you have to guarantee not to return while anything (including autorelease pools) holds a reference to the stack object.

Comment: Right. And the point on passing it to an API is quite true, it's not possible to guarantee it won't receive unwanted messages. Then there would need to exist an automatic way to move that object to the heap and put it on an auto-release pool, once it receives a memory related message. Maybe we will see something like that in Objective-C 3.0 :-)

Comment: @sidyll: There's so little benefit to that, I don't see why they would waste time on it for any version of Objective-C. If you don't want to worry about memory management, you can just use GC or ARC.

Comment: @Chuck: Yes, I see. I was just kidding about objc 3.0 . Anyway, this question was motivated mostly by curiosity. I should now stop placing comments on bbum's answer (sorry bbum) and accept it. Thanks Chuck and everyone for your help.

Answer (score -1):

In theory you can get a chunk of stack storage (eg, `char[NN]`)and pass it to `init`.  [Or maybe not -- it's not clear how the code decides which `init` to invoke -- might need to set the class first, at least.]  What's unknown (and undocumented/unsupported) is to what extent the rest of the code depends on whatever initialization `alloc` does.  Certainly the reference count will not be valid (and probably should somehow be initialized to a large value).  `dealloc` would not be called on frame exit, of course, and a stripped-down version of it would need to be called explicitly.

Comment: Nope;  can't do that.  Objects are designed to be on the heap and all of the system framework APIs assume exactly that.  One random `retain` followed by `autorelease` and **boom**.

Comment: Which is why you'd want to preset the reference count to a high number.  And sidyll and I both know this is "unsupported squared" -- definitely a "use at your own risk" deal.

Comment: Yep, I guess that is a hazard -- if someone does an autorelease on the object its ref count would be decremented even though it's gone, causing stack corruption.  But generally one would not use a stack allocated object in a way that would cause it to be autoreleased -- you're certainly not going to return it!

Comment: The problem, though, is that you can't pass it to *any* system API, nor can you subclass `NSObject` (since there may be -- is, last I looked -- functionality on it that will trigger an autoreleased), thus rendering such an object pretty useless.

Comment: Offhand, I can't think of any reason why calling an API would trigger an autorelease.  Of course, if you place a reference to the object in another object, that's a different beast -- you could do it but you'd have to be sure that the other object would be disposed first, or at least the pointer nulled out.  Don't know what you mean by NSObject -- what functionality are you referring to?

Comment: Deleted my comments and moved 'em to my answer.  (Sorry, Daniel, for making it seem like you are talking to yourself.  If you delete your responses and post a succinct question based on my edits to my answer, I'll try to answer it.)